# how to get the value if Count is 0 mysql | Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

i'm currently working with data where it shows a lot of Province. my query is fine, but i want to display where the value is null in Province.

this is my query

```
$province = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT new_form_participants.province, 
    COUNT(*) AS jumlah FROM new_forms,new_form_participants 
    WHERE new_forms.id = new_form_participants.form_id AND 
    new_forms.is_published = 1 AND new_form_participants.is_published = 1 AND DATE(new_forms.updated_at) 
    BETWEEN '$reqfrom' AND '$reqto' GROUP BY new_form_participants.province"));
```

and this is the example of the result:

```
{
    "province": "Jawa Tengah",
    "jumlah": 8
  },
  {
    "province": "Sulawesi Selatan",
    "jumlah": 2
  },
  {
    "province": "Jawa Barat",
    "jumlah": 19
  },
  {
    "province": "Aceh",
    "jumlah": 2
  }, 
}
```

to get the data to be displayed:

```
@foreach ($province as $key => $data)
                                <tbody>
                                    <th width="50px" class="text-right">{{ $key + 1 }}</th>
                                    <th class="text-left">{{ $data->province }}</th>
                                    <th class="text-left">{{ $data->jumlah }}</th>
                                </tbody>
                            @endforeach
```

Comment: Add a ` AND province IS NULL` to the `WHERE` part of the query, but if these are your results, there are no NULL values in the province field, so it would just generate an empty query. `GROUP BY` should handle `NULL` values just fine, if they don't show, they are not there within the current `WHERE`

Comment: okay  i will check it first

Comment: it returns empty array when i add AND Province IS NULL

Comment: So there just is no data with Province IS NULL in your table, as I predicted. IF you want to check that, just run the same query but without `COUNT(*)` and without `GROUP BY new_form_participants.province`.

Comment: okay i'll check,

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use the query to select the results where province = NULL, you could also check in the foreach loop if($data->province==NULL){...} and only display if that's true.
Hope that makes sense to you.

Comment: okay, i will try it first and then come back here